# Issue with SQL Output from sub-query

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, db2, subquery

I am starting using SQL sub-queries using a python notebook (IBM Watson studio) and there is an issue I cannot figure out.

I have 2 DB2 tables

1. `chicago_socioeconomic_data` which contains a hardship index grouped by community area
2. `CHICAGO_SCHOOLS` which contain academic achievement grouped by community area too

I need to run the following query:

```
%%sql 
select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, hardship_index from chicago_socioeconomic_data
    where COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME = (select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME from CHICAGO_SCHOOLS group by COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME having sum(COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT) = 4368)
```

The thing is the school with college_enrollment = 4368 belongs to Albany Part community area, so the output of the entire sub-query should yield 'Albany Park' to make the main query output the hardship index for Albany Park. Instead it results in an empty output table. If I manually input 'Albany Park' such as below, it works so I know the code itself is correct. I just need to know the behind-the-scenes reason why this doesn't work. Thanks!

```
%%sql 
select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, hardship_index from chicago_socioeconomic_data
    where COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME = 'Albany Park'
```

Comment: Your query should generate an error in any database that I know of because the subquery returns two columns but that is being compared to only one column.

Comment: You're right. It should read like this. I edited the original comment. Still doesn't yield the result I'm looking for.

Comment: There are 2 other potential problems.  One is when the subquery returns more than one row, for which you could use `WHERE x IN (SELECT ...)`, instead of the `=` operator.  The other problem is when the string name isn't the same in both tables.  Compare the column types and values carefully.

Comment: Check that the column definitions in the two tables are the same. Check for trailing spaces in values.